# wordpress sql regex to find urls starting with http not matching my own domain

Tags: php, sql, regex, wordpress

I need an sql query to find all posts (inside `post_content`) containing urls starting exactly by `http://`, but not matching my own domain to avoid finding posts containing internal links.

I know that it can be done and I'm currently using this:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%http://%' ORDER BY ID ASC" );
```

The problem with this is that I can find all urls starting by `http://`, but I also see posts containing internal links.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE post_content LIKE '%http://%' AND
      post_content NOT LIKE '%http://<mydomain>%'
```

Comment: Not really. What I need is a bit harder... I need to get all posts that have an external URL not starting by `http://` regardless if  I have internal links on that post '%http://<mydomain>%' I think this must be done with regex..?